# What are some ways I can convert a string to a number?

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory

I am trying to generate a [Code 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_11) Barcode, from strings, but I can't quite figure out a formulaic way to do this.

I have a list of products and product names, and the barcode readers require numbers. I also want to ensure that the digit generated doesn't clash with any barcode digits for any products that the store currently has in inventory -- that's why I haven't done something "simple" like 00000001, etc.

Say I have a list of product names like this:

- Eye Chart
- John Wago
- Very Long Product Name 1
- Extra Very Long Product Name 20

Ideally I would love to be able to generate an 11-digit code that fits this [Code 11 Barcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_11) Standard.

P.S. I don't know how to categorize this post, so can someone more knowledgeable than I properly tag this question please.

Comment: The only surefire way is to have a database, and check for collisions directly.  There are hash functions that do sort of what you want, but their output is much larger than 11 digits.  Eleven digits is only enough to encode about five or six letters if you treat them all equally.  Even a Huffman code would probably only get that up to eight, maybe?

Comment: There's no direct way because the possible space of such strings is larger than 11-digit base-10 numbers. So you'll need some kind of association table like a hash which handles collisions gracefully.

Comment: ok thanks guys! I appreciate the feedback